# Android ImageButton image comparison with a variable which holds the image

Tags: android, variables, compare, android-imagebutton

I want to compare drawables. The two drawables are in an ImageButton and a variable which holds the other drawable to compare with.

Here is my code

```
option1.setImageResource(questionsLibrary.getOption1(questionID));

correctAnswer = questionsLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(questionID);
```

option1 is an ImageButton while correctAnswer is a variable that holds a drawable.

I want to compare them both to check if the option1 and correctAnswer has the same drawable.

Comment: Drawable is an abstract class. Do you know if correctAnswer references the same drawable subclass as the ImageButton? If they are the same, would that mean that the option1 drawable came from the same resource as the ImageButton?

Comment: @JoeMjr2 option1 is the imagebutton. i want to compare the value of option1 with correctAnswer which is an array that hold the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather comparing drawable, take an advantage of tag property of a view. Set tag of `option1.setTag("Answer or unique key")`. Then compare it by fetching tag value from ImageButton `option1.getTag()`.

Comment: i cant set tag to it as option1 is going to be used repeatedly.

Comment: Update its tag repeatedly, or maintain HashMap with key as question id

Comment: can you give a hint or a code snippet of updating tag repeatedly.

Comment: from where you were setting option1.setImageResource(questionsLibrary.getOption1(questionID)); now set tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(option1.getDrawable().getConstantState().equal(correctAnswer.getConstantState())){
   //Your code here
}
```

Comment: correctAnswer has no option for getConstantState as correctAnswer is a variable which hold the drawable and not the drawable itself. :/

Comment: You can't compare an entire array to a drawable. You can only compare a single element of the array.

Comment: @JoeMjr2 correctAnswer hold the value of a function which get the value of a single array element in another class. Should i post the entire codes?